# A question related to "supremum"

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $f\in L_{p}([0,1])$ and $[a,c]\subset [0,1].$ Is there an inequality between the following quantities?
$$
\underset{|h|\leq b-a}{\sup}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx+
\underset{|h|\leq c-b}{\sup}\int_{b}^{c}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx 
$$
and
$$
\underset{|h|\leq\max\{b-a,\, c-b\}}{\sup}\int_{a}^{c}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx
$$

Comment: No, this is false. There's no reason to expect this to be true, when on the right you allow a wider range of $h$ in the supremum. Perhaps you wanted an inequality between these quantities?

Comment: Thank you. Is there an inequality between these quantities?